# bootstrap fail with installing VCPKG

Tags: vcpkg

I am new with vcpkg and visual studio.

I did install VS and it was easy, but with vcpkg I keep having error when running the command:
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat

I keep receiving the same error:
[image]

By the way I downloaded the .zip file for vcpkg from GIT but I make sure to run the command with the correct path. I also did check that it is the latest version available under GIT.

Any help plz!

Comment: In my case, it failed because my powershell version was not updated. It needed powershell 7.2.3. Once I double-clicked vcpkg.exe prsent in vcpkg folder, it downloaded the required powershell zip file on its own in ~\vcpkg\downloads. After that I installed powershell after unzipping it. Issue was solved.

Comment: Just updating this with a solution that worked for me: I simply did a work around in the "Bootstap.ps1" file located in "scripts" folder by commenting some lines that throw an error like: "$scriptsDir/tls12-download.exe" github.com "/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/releases/download/$versionDate/vcpkg.exe" "$vcpkgRootDir\vcpkg.exe" and the if loop just after with this command: Write-Error "Downloading vcpkg.exe failed. Please check your internet connection....."           I hope this help!